# Android server client problems

Tags: java, android, client

I'm hoping someone out there can help me, I am trying to create a basic application that transmits GPS co ordinates of the device to a server. I am a complete noobie to socket programming (well, I covered the bare basics in college this year).

As a stepping stone, I am following an online tutorial, that creates the server, and the android client, it is designed to send an input from the user to the server and the server prints it on the console.
I'm becoming quite familar with how to set up the basics of the server and the client i.e. opening ports etc. The problem with this is, when hit send, the app crashes, when tested on the emulator, there is obviously an issue, but I can't see it.

When I test with device, and hit send, there is nothing printed to the console. I've attached both the client and server code below, the ip in the code below is for the emulator, I change this to my device ip with testing with it.

****SERVER****

```
public class Additional_Server {
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private static String message;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2001); // Server socket
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 2001");
    }
    System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 2001");
    while (true) {
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
            message = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(message);
            inputStreamReader.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
        }
    }
}
```

}

****CLIENT****

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class TCPclient extends Activity {
private Socket client;
private PrintWriter printwriter;
private EditText textField;
private Button button;
private String messsage;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tcpclient);
        textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Msg); // reference to the text field
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend); // reference to the send button
        // Button press event listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                messsage = textField.getText().toString(); // get the text message on    the text field
                textField.setText(""); // Reset the text field to blank
                try {
                    client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2001); // connect to server
                    printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),
                            true);
                    printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream
                    printwriter.flush();
                    printwriter.close();
                    client.close(); // closing the connection
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Any pointers, advice or help is greatly appreciated as what I'm seeing looks correct, but there's obviously something incorrect. Thanking you in advance!!!

Gary

I've edited the above code to put it into an async task as suggested, the emulator isn't crashing, however, I still can't get any printout to the console..can anyone help?  I'm trying here, I'm just not very used to android, and this is the best way to learn....

```
public class TCPclient extends Activity {

private Socket client;
private PrintWriter printwriter;
private EditText textField;
private Button button;
private String messsage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tcpclient);

    textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Msg);  // reference to the text field
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);     // reference to the send button
    messsage = textField.getText().toString();      // get the text message on the text field

    // Button press event listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            textField.setText(""); // Reset the text field to blank
            new commAsyncTask().execute();
        }

        class commAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    client = new Socket("192.168.1.2", 2001); // connect to
                                                                // server
                    printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());



                    printwriter.println(messsage); 
                    printwriter.flush();
                    printwriter.close();


                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

}

So folks please, there are a lot of people out there a lot wiser than me and your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should not perform this task in the UI thread. Create a separate Thread or carry it out in an `AsynTask`

Answer (score 0):

tl dr - threads

Basically in Android the UI is running on a thread as well as your code. So the socket code is stopping it from running the UI portion which causes the Android OS to think that the app is not responding (or something similar) and therefore it crashes.

edit:
To fix put the sock in another thread via a thread or async task or something

Comment: Thanks folks for the input.  I think I have an idea, so I do my interface within the TCPclient, create a separate class extending ASyncTask containing the duties to be carried out, then, within the onClick method, call/ execute that class?  I'm sorry, but this is brand new to me!!f

Comment: Could someone tell me if the above is correct?  So if I use an async task that it should run?

Comment: @DJ-DOO that's what I saw an example use. I personally am going to use a thread but my application is basically constantly pushing data.

Comment: mine would also be doing the same, it will be continually transmitting the gps co ordinates, so I'm probably better using a different thread..?

Comment: Is there no one here that can help me?  Or is it the case that no one will?

Comment: @ thinkijustwon I went and tried to put the above into an Async task, now, the emulator isn't crashing, however, I'm still not getting the printout to the console...